# Remove event data tables from wso2 Data Analytics Server

Tags: apache-spark, wso2, siddhi, wso2-das

I have created some test tables in `WSO2-DataAnalyticsServer-3.0.1` by these steps:
Edit Event>Streams>Next[presistEvent]
then enable Persist Event Stream and Save.
This made a table which is showing on InteractiveAnalytics>Data Explorer. I want to remove this table but I do not how and where I should do this.

Answer (score 5):

You can delete such tables using the [analytics data backup / restore tool](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48288726).

To delete the tables use the below command by replacing the table names that you want to delete under **-tables** for example I have set it as table1,table2. Run this command after navigating to WSO2_DAS_HOME/bin folder,

`./analytics-backup.sh -deleteTables -tables "table1,table2" -tenantId -1234`

this will delete the two tables, table1 & table2.